# Error when trying to run my Angular Schematics

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular-schematics

When running `schematics .:schema` from the root folder of my project, I get the following error:

```
An error occured:
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/pete/Desktop/projects/Angular/DEV/SchematicsDemo/src/my-component/index'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/bin/schematics.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:793:17)
    at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:80:19)
    at new ExportStringRef (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js:16:32)
    at NodeModulesEngineHost._resolveReferenceString (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/node-module-engine-host.js:95:21)
    at NodeModulesEngineHost.createSchematicDescription (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/file-system-engine-host-base.js:174:34)
    at SchematicEngine.createSchematic (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:215:38)
    at CollectionImpl.createSchematic (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:70:29)
    at NodeWorkflow.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/workflow/base.js:105:38)
    at main (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/bin/schematics.js:229:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/bin/schematics.js:336:5)
```

I am following the tutorial from this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5YSPas3qFo&t=1707s and he receives the same error on his first attempt at 32:30.

To fix it, he runs `npm run build:watch` but I receive this error when trying to do the same

```
npm ERR! missing script: build:watch

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/pete/.npm/_logs/2020-12-26T17_18_10_036Z-debug.log
```

Here is my `angular.json` file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "SchematicsDemo": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/SchematicsDemo",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "SchematicsDemo:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "SchematicsDemo:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "SchematicsDemo:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "SchematicsDemo:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "SchematicsDemo:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "SchematicsDemo"
}
```

Not sure how to fix this issue, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the file in that exact path exist? You could try to use different than index file name (and adjust collection.json to reflect that change) as index is sometimes resolved in weird ways based on module resolution settings.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is already logged in github, you can keep eye on the same using #12230.

But till then it is resolved, you can use below work around you have to tweak angular.json a bit

Change

```
projects.YOUR-APP-NAME.targets
```

To

```
projects.YOUR-APP-NAME.architect
```

Comment: I do not see anything like this in my `angular.json` file... I will add the file to the original post.

Comment: Looks like there is already "architect" property in the angular.json as provided in the question.